# google appengine giving me DownloadError

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, urllib

```
import urllib
img = urllib.urlopen('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=000000|12|h|FFFFFF|_|testinf foobar').read()
```

I am trying above code using google appengine.

**Local:** It is running fine.

**On Delpyment**: Its giving me error

```
Exception Type: DownloadError
Exception Value:    
ApplicationError: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DownloadError` 2 is a timeout. Use [urlfetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) directly, and set a longer timeout using the `deadline` argument.